# Responsive Design for mobile view with boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I recently got help on an issue I got and the final code is in the code section.  Now I have just recognized that for smartphone view it does not look the way I want it. The current format is as follows:

```text
Image | Text   
Text | Image   
Image | Text   
Text | Image
```

For mobile view it should be:

```
Image 
Text 
Image 
Text 
Image 
Text 
Image 
Text
```

The format for the second and fourth row have to be changed for the mobile view, in order to have the order image - text - image - text etc. For mobile view I have this section: `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){}`. Also, does it make sense to have a separate class for each row? Can you please help?

```css
.h1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.text {
  font-size: 24px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.desc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image,
.text {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.image img {
  max-width: 80%;
}

.left {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.right {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="h1">Headline</div>
<div class="desc">
  <div class="image left">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image right">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
  </div>
  <div class="image left">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image right">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by updating your CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
  .desc {
      flex-direction: column;
  }

  .desc > div:first-of-type{
    order: 1;
  }
  
  .desc > div:nth-last-of-type(2){
    order: 2;
  }
  
  .desc > div:nth-last-of-type(3){
    order: 4;
  }
  
  .desc > div:nth-last-of-type(4){
    order: 3;
  }
  
  .desc > div:nth-last-of-type(5){
    order: 5;
  }
  
  .desc > div:nth-last-of-type(6){
    order: 6;
  }
  
  .desc > div:nth-last-of-type(7){
    order: 8;
  }
  
  .desc > div:nth-last-of-type(8){
    order: 7;
  }
}
```

and don't forget to add a viewport in your HTML head if you want the media query to work on mobile devices  :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your help. Okay cool let me try that.

I have seen this "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">" many times, but didn't not understand what it does. Would you mind briefly explain it? I wanted to add it randomly, but did not know what it really does.

Comment: Sure , this meta gives you as a designer the ability to take control over viewport which  gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.
You can discover it more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) , enjoy!

Comment: If answer helps, you can vote up and accept the answer thankfully

Answer (score 0):

Think mobile first and update your html code:

```css
.desc {
  display: grid;
}
@media (min-width:768px) {
  .desc {
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr; /* 2 columns only on big screen */
    grid-auto-flow:dense; /* fill all the area */
  }
  .image:nth-child(4n + 3) {
      grid-column:2; /* move the each second image to the second column */
  }
}

.image,
.text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.image img {
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image ">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yeah you are right I have read that many times. I have recently started with HTML therefore still need practice. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to restructure your code into groupings as follows:

```html
<div class="content-block">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
  </div>
  
  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

then you could rewrite the css for your markup in a more compact way that would prevent the need for adding more `:nth-of-type` statements to your css every time you added a new piece of text or an image.

This css could be written as follows and would account for both mobile and larger breakpoints:

```css
.content-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.image,
.text {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.image img {
  max-width: 80%;
}


.content-block:nth-of-type(even) .image {
  order: 2;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .content-block {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .content-block .image {
    order: 1;
  }
  
  .content-block .text {
    order: 2;
  }
}

/* Styles from here and downward can be ignored - they are just for clarity of the example using colours/spacings */
.content-block {
  background: aliceblue;
  color: black;
 }
```

```html
<div class="desc">
  <div class="content-block">
    <div class="image left">
      Image here
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <b>Text</b>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content-block">
    <div class="image left">
      Image here
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <b>Text</b>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content-block">
    <div class="image left">
      Image here
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <b>Text</b>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes this is more compact. I will check this again.